# Import data from excel to mysql using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

I have Excel file shown bellow

[image]

I want to read 1st read only all school names & school address & insert them in SchoolInfo table of mySql database.

After that I want to read data for each school & insert it in StudentsInfo table which has foreign key associated with SchoolInfo table.

I am reading excel sheet something like this.

public static void Import(string fileName)
    {
        string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName +
                         ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"";

```
    var output = new DataSet();

    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        var dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

        if (dt != null)
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string sheet = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [+"+sheet+"+]", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                OleDbDataAdapter xlAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                xlAdapter.Fill(output,"School");
            }
    }

}
```

Now I am having data in datatable of dataset, Now how do I read desired data & insert it in my sql table.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Reading from Excel sheet

First you must create an OleDB connection to the Excel file.

```
String connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
"Data Source=" + path + ";" +
"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
OleDbConnection xlConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
xlConn.Open();
```

Here path refers to the location of your Excel spreadsheet. E.g. "D:\abc.xls"
Then you have to query your table. For this we must define names for the table and columns first. Click here to find out how.
Now create the command object.

```
OleDbCommand selectCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", xlConn);
```

Now we have to store the ouput of the select command into a DataSet using a DataAdapter

```
OleDbDataAdapter xlAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
objAdapter1.SelectCommand = selectCmd;
DataSet xlDataset = new DataSet();
xlAdapter.Fill(xlDataset, "XLData");
```

1. Save the data into variables

Now extract cell data into variables iteratively for the whole table by using

```
variable = xlDataset.Tables[0].Rows[row_value][column_value].ToString() ;
```

1. Write the data from the variables into the MySQL database

Now connect to the MySQL database using an ODBC connection

```
String mySqlConnectionString = "driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" +
"server=localhost;" + "database=;" + "user=;" + "password=;";
OdbcConnection mySqlConn = new OdbcConnection(mySqlConnectionString);
mySqlConn.Open();
```

Construct your INSERT statement using the variables in which data has been stored from the Excel sheet.

```
OdbcCommand mySqlInsert = new OdbcCommand(insertCommand, mySqlConn);
mySqlInsert.ExecuteScalar()
```

Comment: I know how can we read excel file & all. Real problem is multiple data i.e. school1, school2, etc. How do I manipulate for reading these values